# 2.79b to run script using command line in windows, preferably with a desktop shortcut or exe

Tags: export, command-line

Here's the code i have written so far, it's working inside blender text editor.
I however like to run this script without opening blender, with command-line, better yet to create a shortcut icon on a PC to run it, hoping to make this friendly and available for people who do not know blender well.

```
import bpy
import os

# get the current path and make a new folder for the exported meshes
path = bpy.path.abspath('//stl/')

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)



# deselect all meshes
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# select the object
#object.select = True
object = bpy.data.objects['pboard']
object.hide_select = False
object.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = object

# export object with its name as file name
fPath = str((path + object.name + '.stl'))

#bpy.context.active_object = object
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath=fPath, use_selection=True)


object.hide_select = True
```

Comment: That all looks good. Have you got permissions to write to the /stl folder? are there any errors reported in the console? can you show the complete command line you are using?

Comment: @rob thx i got this running, hv edited the question to focus on the part on how to get this running with the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the *blender.exe* and **Right Click** and select **Create Shortcut**

[image: create shortcut in windows]

Due to permissions I cannot create a shortcut in the Blender folder so it offers to create it on the Desktop.

Find the shortcut and **Right Click** and select **Properties**

[image: shortcut properties in windows]

In the **Target** box append

```
 -b c:\tmp\target.blend --python c:\tmp\exportscript.py
```

to the fully quoted *blender.exe* 
e.g.

```
"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe" -b c:\tmp\target.blend --python c:\tmp\exportscript.py
```

Where *target.blend* is the blender file with the "**pboard**" object to export and *exportscript.py* is the original posters code with the "**path**" value set to match your environment.

I created a c:\tmp folder that has full permissions for the blender user and set the path

```
path = "C:\\tmp\\stl\\"
```

Now when I double click the shortcut, a command window flashes open briefly before closing. The file C:\tmp\stl\pboard.stl" is then available.